# Help understanding 最高のアングルっていうのは魂の叫びなのよ

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm unsure of how to correctly parse the below. I originally thought that it might have had, for example, an implied part of the sentence  before e.g. ここを　最高のアングルっていうのは魂の叫びなのよ。However this doesn't quite sound right to me, and if it was going to be something like that I would have imagined って言う　or って言っている instead of っていう.

I think part of my problem is that I am not entirely clear on the meaning of 魂の叫び, and how it works in this sentence.

> 「**最高のアングルっていうのは魂の叫びなのよ**。ここを狙えって訴えてくるの。逆らえないのよ」

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the pattern,「～というのは...」?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a metaphorical sentence, and nothing is omitted. Or perhaps you can think ～のような ("like") is implied. 魂の叫び ("soul cry/scream") is not an idiomatic phrase but her own tricky metaphor. Her intention is clearly explained in the next sentence.

～というのは/～っていうのは is like an emphatic topic marker, and it's often used to describe a definition or an important characteristic of something. For example:

> 人生は長い旅だ。
>   ≒人生とは長い旅だ。
>   ≒人生というのは長い旅だ。
>   ≒人生っていうのは長い旅だ。
>   ≒人生っていうのは長い旅のようなものだ。
>
> Life is (like) a long journey.

With this in mind, your sentence is an example of personification:

> 最高のアングルっていうのは魂の叫びなのよ。ここを狙えって訴えてくるの。逆らえないのよ。
>   "The best (camera) angle" is (like) a soul scream. It (= the angle itself) tells me "Shoot this". I cannot resist.

So, to put it plainly, she seems to be saying "good photographers don't worry about camera angle because they can decide the right angle by intuition."